# reloading capcha landing to top portion not to the capcha portion

Tags: php, parallax

I am using simple captcha code in my contact form.

```
<div class="col-md-4" onload="Captcha();">
                                                <label>Enter Captcha *</label>
                                                <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter captcha" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="captcha" id="captcha" required>

                                    <img src="captcha.php" id="captacha-image">
<span onClick="
    document.getElementById('captacha-image').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
     id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</span>


        </div>
```

The problem is while reloading the capcha image. the whole page reloads and page landing on top. The contact form is in the footer part of my page.

Answer (score 0):

You missed href value:

```
<a href="#" onClick="
    document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
    id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</a>
```

Comment: You have duplicated id selector, rename selector for img to captacha-image and with: document.getElementById('captacha-image') its working for me

Comment: I tested this with button so if you want to make sure there is no refresh replace <a> with <span>